# Diagnosing Dead MoBo/Other PC Component

Tags: boot, laptop, memory, motherboard

basically I have this HP G60-445DX Notebook that is showing some odd signs. These signs are atypical to what I've normally seen in fried mobos. In short, no graphics, no POST beeps, HDD light blinking, power button blinks when no RAM is installed. The last two of those symptoms make it seem like the mobo is fine. Neither the trackpad disable button or the wifi button works, indicating that the mobo is bad. I have no idea what to think.

I have done the basic tests: power drain, external monitor, different RAM sticks, CMOS reset, yadda yadda yadda.

Is there any chance I could get some help on this?

P.S. the monitor backlight does not come on, but looking closely, I cannot see any graphics. Is there any way I can test to see if the monitor is good?

Comment: You have provided enough information to determine what is wrong with your hardware

Comment: Then would you mind being helpful and providing some insight? Clearly if the mobo's LEDs respond to varying conditions, it cannot be completely fried. At least, that's my thought process.

Comment: he meant you have ***NOT*** provided enough info.  go into extreme detail.  Yadda yadda yadda doesn not cut it.

Comment: I've done every test you can do on a laptop other than exposing the mobo and testing with a multimeter.